# Comparison between solid rocket fuels. Which are better by performance and cost?

Tags: fuel, cost, solid-fuel, specific-impulse, performance

I am interested for a comparison of solid rocket fuels by their performance and cost. Comparison by specific impulse (Isp), energy that gives (which one is more energitic), density, cost to manifacture them, cost per kg (or pound), and also other elements if you could find. Comparing them in a table would be better. Even if there are included some of the values for these elements, it is still ok. For any further info that you will find later about them, you can edit the answer.

Comment: Its an interesting question though you could get a fair way by putting "comparison of solid rocket fuels" into a search engine. This would be a good way to refine your question - I'm sure there are folks here who'd be interested to help work through any problems you find. Please see http://space.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You will find this information in books and materials labeled mostly with "pyrotechnics". Here [is a table](http://www.lr.tudelft.nl/en/organisation/departments/space-engineering/space-systems-engineering/expertise-areas/space-propulsion/system-design/generate-candidates/comparison-of-rockets/) that lists some of the common solid propellant combinations, and here [is a online database](http://pyrodata.com/composition/rocket-propellants). And here is a short [historical overview](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/dryden/pdf/88635main_H-2330.pdf) of what came from where.

I don't think you'll find good cost data anywhere except shopping around for Estes motors by yourself, but I'd recommend looking around on [Richard Nakka's excellent](http://www.nakka-rocketry.net/propel.html#Introduction) hobby solid propellant project pages.